# Unable to enlarge the size of the modal form textbox

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I was not able to enlarge the size of the textboxes in the modal form, after multiple replacements of the text 'col-sm-20' to 'input-lg', I wasn't quite sure why it still remained the same,  please find out why thanks!

```html
<div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <label style="font-family:Lato; font-size:20pt; font-weight:normal;" for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-left ">Created At:</label>
  <div class='col-sm-5'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control col-sm-15 row align-items-center justify-content-center" id='datetimepicker4' disabled />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <label style="font-family:Lato; font-size:20pt; font-weight:normal;" for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-left">Updated At:</label>
  <div class='col-sm-5'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control col-sm-15 row align-items-center justify-content-center" id='datetimepicker5' disabled/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button style="font-size:20px; background-color:orange ;" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- DateTimePicker -->



<!-- navigation bar & Dropdown menu -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Boostrap 4.x has no class `input-lg`, it is only in ver3.x

Comment: how do I resolve this? what bootstrap should I put in order to work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copied the `input-lg` styles from bootstrap 3.3.7 for you. Please check if that is your desire output. FYI, the maximum number to set for col is 12 (e.g. col-sm-12) and it has to use with parent class `row` to take effect.

```css
.input-lg {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <label style="font-family:Lato; font-size:20pt; font-weight:normal;" for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-left ">Created At:</label>
  <div class='col-sm-5'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg row align-items-center justify-content-center" id='datetimepicker4' disabled />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <label style="font-family:Lato; font-size:20pt; font-weight:normal;" for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-left">Updated At:</label>
  <div class='col-sm-5'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg row align-items-center justify-content-center" id='datetimepicker5' disabled/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button style="font-size:20px; background-color:orange ;" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- DateTimePicker -->



<!-- navigation bar & Dropdown menu -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, everything works great ! may I know to adjust the text box size, should I adjust it by lowering the height?

Comment: Yes, just set the height. If you can't see the text properly, you may play around with other properties in the `.input-lg`